# Azure Front Door - configure maintenance page

Tags: azure-front-door

I got AFD with 1 FE web app on it. I want to add another web application that hold maintenance/sorry page. 
All URLs from FE need to be cached, sorry page image must not be cached.
I tried to add my sorry page web app to same backend pool with low priority and weight. When i turn off FE, it redirect to sorry page web app, but it caches content.
And as i understood, i cannot use another backend pool (to disable caching ), cause 2 pools cannot be connected to same AFD FE endpoint.

Any thoughts how can maintenance page web app be added to AFD? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may not fully answer your question, in theory, another approach is to use path based routing on the site via a routing rule in Front Door.  So site.com/error would be setup to forward to potentially another host that lives outside of Front Door to prevent caching.

Answer (score 1):

AFD doesn't have a feature to have custom Error page as of today. Adding the error page to the same backend pool is not a right way as the members of the same backend pool should contain the same content.

In Frontdoor you will not be able to do it. You can use Application Gateway where you can point to the maintenance page based on the backend server response (502 or 403)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple options.

you can do this as follows:

1. create maintenance page as staging web app in azure storage.
   I recommend go over this option because you future automated script will be not so complex.
2. Rule engine ->  create rule engine configuration with no condition and action to  maintenance page ( redirect 302 f.e.) and go to rule and update manually/from script  Rule Engine Configuration for rule.
3. Manually on Rule page, update route type to Redirect and setup custom host and path to maintenance page.

M

Answer (score 0):

We are in 2024 and Azure Front Door still doesn't support custom error/maintenance pages. It may be helpful to ask for this feature by providing feedback to Azure and upvoting here:

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/76e41f9c-8626-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789