# What is the best way to provide Asp.Net Core health information to end users?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, health-monitoring, azure-front-door

### Context

I'm looking for a way to tell my users that one of the dependencies of my Asp.Net Core site is down and that therefore the site is currently not available. Preferably using an error page.

Asp.Net Core provides the [Health Checks functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks) to manage the logic of dependency health checking, but it only provides an endpoint meant for load-balancers.
There is also a kind of [dashboard functionality](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#healthcheckui-and-failure-notifications) available for the health checks but that is not meant as an error page for end users, it is aimed at administrators.

### Why am I looking into this functionality?

I am using Azure Front Door. This product works as a load balancer. It can look at the health status endpoint provided by Asp.Net Core health checks and will take unhealthy backend nodes out of rotation.

However, [it does not offer custom error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59421987/1114918) and [in the case that all backend nodes are down, it will assume that all nodes are healthy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-health-probes#complete-health-probe-failure). One of the dependencies of my site is an external service that, if it is down, will be down for all instances of my site. It contains e.g. the user accounts that are needed for users to interact with my site. Therefore, I believe I need to implement an error page in the Asp.Net Core site that will show an error page when that external dependency is down.

### Suggested solution

One of my ideas would be to have middleware that, when the site is degraded, always returns `503 Service Unavailable` or throw an exception. The [Asp.Net Core Status Page functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#usestatuscodepages-with-lambda) could then turn that in an appropriate error page.

### Question 1

Is this the best architecture? How have other people done this?

### Question 2

What is the most practical way to access the current health status?

Technically it is possible to call the [`HealthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.diagnostics.healthchecks.healthcheckservice.checkhealthasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Diagnostics_HealthChecks_HealthCheckService_CheckHealthAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method directly, but awaiting that method takes some time (especially if one of the dependency services does not respond). Therefore it is not a good idea to make that blocking in the request pipeline.

I could use a [`Health Check Publisher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#health-check-publisher) to cache the health status by publishing it to some custom `HealthStatusCache` service, but it feels a bit like a workaround. Is this how other people would do it?

Comment: This seems a little black and white.

If one of the dependencies is unavailable, do you want the entire site to be unavailable?  Better recourse would be to offer a degraded but still useful experience, if at all possible.

Comment: I added some more context - my site depends on an external system containing the users' accounts and login functionality. If that is down, I cannot provide a degraded experience to the users besides some static content. That is why I want to have such a kind of "offline page".